# How to modify or replace key inside Array of Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Below Array is Actual Array and How to change key like 0,1,2,3 to A,B,C,D

```
let Array1=[
  0: {
    name: abc
   },
  1: {
    name: abc
   },
  2: {
    name: abc
   },
  3: {
    name: abc
   }
  ];
```

Expected Array

```
let Array1=[
  A: {
    name: abc
   },
  B: {
    name: abc
   },
  C: {
    name: abc
   },
  D: {
    name: abc
   }
  ];
```

As per above conversion How to convert Actual Array to Expected Array in Javascript, Please give me solution.

Comment: As it is your code is formatted incorrectly. Are you dealing with an array of objects, or an object with sub objects? For example, this is invalid: `Array1=[A:{name=abc}]` This is invalid because you are treating the array like an key-value pair object (also you need to quote your strings and use the appropriate `'key':'value'` syntax). Please fix your example into something that actually works, then we can discuss how to update keys.

Comment: you are  asking for an invalid syntax

Comment: the values `0,1,2,3` doesn't belong to the real array, they are just made by the console inspector for reading clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to convert key `i` to the `i`th letter of the alphabet (and assuming you don't go beyond `i = 25`), you can use [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) and the fact that `65` translates to `A`:

```js
const newArray1 = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(Array1).map(
    ([key, value]) => [String.fromCharCode(65 + parseInt(key)), value]
  )
)
```

This will convert `{0: {...}, 1: {...}, 2: {...}, 3: {...}}` or `[{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}]` into `{A: {...}, B: {...}, C: {...}, D: {...}}`.

Comment: Did you try that on this invalid array? `let Array1=[
  0: {
    name: abc
   },
  1: {
    name: abc
   },
  2: {
    name: abc
   },
  3: {
    name: abc
   }
  ];`

Comment: I guess you're joking? I assumed that the `[]`s were typos and the meaning was either `{   0: {     name: abc    },   1: {     name: abc    },   2: {     name: abc    },   3: {     name: abc    }   }` or `[   {     name: abc    },   {     name: abc    },   {     name: abc    },   {     name: abc    }   ]`.

Comment: Don’t assume. Op likely pasted some console output

Answer (score 1):

Can be done like this:

```js
 const arr = [{ name: "abc" }, { name: "def" }, { name: "ghi" }];

    const entries = Object.entries(arr);
    console.log(`entries`, entries);

    const res = entries.map(([key, value]) => {
      const newKey = String.fromCharCode(+key + 65);
      return { [newKey]: value };
    });
    console.log(`res`, res);
```